# How to print argv arguments from main function in C?

Tags: c, printf, parameter-passing

So I just learnt that we can give two arguments into main function namely "argc" and "argv. However I am not able to understand what argv is in this:
`int main(int argc, char* argv[]);`

Is argv an array of characters? or is it an array of pointers pointing to characters? Either way I am looking for a way to print out the arguments that the user passes to this program. This is the code the I wrote, but it's not printing the argv's so to speak. What's wrong in it? I guess it's my understanding of argv that's making this code incorrect.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",*argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After the suggestions that I got from answers, I corrected my code as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I am using Ubuntu Linux in VMWare on my windows 8.1 pc. This is the output that I am getting. It's just printing argc and after that nothing. What's the problem? Is it the way I am compiling it or something in Linux terminal?

[image: The snapshot of my terminal]

In the above figure, I want the numbers 2,4,5,3 to be printed again, but they are not getting printed.

Thanks.

Comment: Enable warning in your compiler and pay attention to what it complains about.

Comment: This is interesting; someone is upvoting all answers together...

Comment: I was the one who upvoted all the answers because all of them were right. However my problem is not yet resolved, so I did not choose the right answer yet. and I have no idea who downvoted the answers in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: @everyone Sorry I am new here. So if I edit the question, I guess others who have already answered won't get notified. I read online that I should simply comment here so that others can notice that I have edited my question. So I wanted all of you to know that I have edited my question and I want answer for that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @rohitkrishna094 You are right with your observation, that others are not automatically notified about your edit. Leaving a comment like "Edited my question" does not notify anyone but it helps those who re-visit to immediately notice your update. With so many answers that's enough. If you ever happen to get only a single answer, your best bet is to comment the answer instead of your question - this really notifies the author of the answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's explain things step by step. First of all, when you invoke your program by calling something like...

```
./my-program arg0 arg1 arg2
```

You're passing it a series of three arguments, right? And each argument is a string, right? Now, the `main` function, can have one of two prototypes, as specified by the C standard...

```
int main(); // Let's not worry about this for now
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

The idea is that `main` is able to handle the arguments that you provided. `argc` provides the number of arguments. If you noticed, while passing three arguments, `argc` is 4! This happens because a first argument is passed before all others, `./my-program`, and lets your program recognize itself.

Now, what does `char **argv` mean? Something of the form `X*` is a pointer to `X`, right? So, `char *` is a pointer to `char`, and `char **` is a pointer to pointer to `char`. In C, a string is simply a zero-terminated array of `char`, and an array can be "degraded" into a pointer. This means that `argv` is an array of strings, the first of which, `argv[0]`, is the program's name.

Now, the C standard allows you to write any "compatible" prototype for `main`. For instance, you can write any of these...

```
int main(int argc, const char *const argv[]);
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
int main(int argc, const char **argv);
int main(int argc, const char *const *const argv);
```

You don't need to understand what they all mean now, just that `argv` is an array of strings, and that you should **never** modify strings as the original `main` prototype appears to trust you. Now, knowing that arguments start at `argv[1]`, your code...

```
for(int i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
```

Means: "For each `i` in the range of 0 through `argc - 1`".

```
    printf("%s",*argv[i]);
```

Means: "Print the first character of the `i`th element of `argv`". Why would this be wrong? First of all, you're printing a `char`, and telling `printf` that it is a string. **This has undefined behavior**. Then, you're iterating over the first `i`th elements of `argv`. This means that the first, "non-argument" element will be included in the mix, and the last argument won't be. To solve it, write something like...

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
```

Means: "For each `i` in the range from `1` up to `argc`".

```
    printf("%s", argv[i]);
```

Means: "Print the `i`th element of `argv` to `stdout`.

Comment: Sry, but this "*This means that argv is an array of strings*" (at least taken out of the somewhat misleading context) simply is wrong. `argv` is a pointer to the 1st element of array of pointers to `char`-pointers. With the later referencing `char`-arrays, C-"strings". An "*array of strings*" definitely is something different (`char[47][11]` for example).

Comment: Also the `const` in you example signatures for `main()` is wrong, at least for C.

Answer (score 7):

> Is `argv` an array of characters? or is it an array of pointers pointing to characters?

`argv` is a pointer to pointer to `char`. When a list of arguments are passed through command line then an array of `char` pointers are created and each of these pointers points to each of these arguments, stored in the form of strings, along with the program name. `argv` points to the first pointer of this `char *` array. Therefore, `argv[i]` is a pointer to `char`.

```
                           +--------------------------+
              +----+  +--> | argument 1 (program name)|
argv[0]+----> |    |  |    +--------------------------+
              |  +----+
              +----|       +--------------------------+
              |  +-------> |       argument 2         |
              |    |       +--------------------------+
              +----+
              |  +----+    +--------------------------+
              |    |  +--> |       argument 3         |
              +----+       +--------------------------+
           "char *" array
```

You need to change

```
printf("%s",*argv[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%s",argv[i]);
```

`*argv[i]` is of type `char`. `%s` expects a type of `char *`.

Answer (score 6):

`argv` is a `NULL` terminated array of strings. So one doesn't even need `argc` to print all the arguments passed to the main function. So if `argv` points to `NULL` then that's the end of the arguments passed.

So to sum it up, you can do this with a simple `while` loop, using only `argv`:

```
    while (*argv != NULL)
    {
            printf("%s\n", *argv);
            argv++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`char *argv[]` is pointer to pointer to `char` because arrays in function arguments are automatically converted to pointer pointing at elements of the array.

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `%s` expects `char*`, but you passed `char` (converted to `int` for variable number arguments).

Remove the extra `*` o dereference the pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also you may want `i<argc` instead of `i<argc-1`. Why not print the last argument?

Answer (score 3):

In your edited question you have fixed your main problem. Now notice that your prompt looks like

```
./mygrep245YourName@ubuntu:~/test$
```

Here `./mygrep245` is your output after you printed `"5\n"`. You forgot to print line feeds, thus all the output and the subsequent shell output has been concatenated as it is. And the last argument `3` wasn't printed because you put `i<argc-1` instead of `i<argc` or `i<=argc-1` in your loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the [document](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html):

> As you can see, main now has arguments. The name of the variable argc
>   stands for "argument count"; argc contains the number of arguments
>   passed to the program. The name of the variable argv stands for
>   "argument vector". A vector is a one-dimensional array, and argv is a
>   one-dimensional array of strings. Each string is one of the arguments
>   that was passed to the program.

If you need to print it simply remove the * and try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",argv[i]);   //remove * from here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Regarding

> Is argv an array of characters? or is it an array of pointers pointing to characters?

`argv` is an array of c-strings (where each c-string is a pointer to characters). Consider the following command line:

```
$ your-executable arg1 "arg2 with space"
```

It would result in an array of strings with the following content (pseudo code)

```
argv[0] EQUALS "your-executable"
argv[1] EQUALS "arg1"
argv[2] EQUALS "arg2 with space"
```

As others mentioned, remove the * from `printf("%s", *argv[i]);` and fix your loop condition if you want to print all arguments

Comment: It'ld be better not to teach the OP to do things like `if(argv[0] == "your-executable")` in real code...

Comment: BTW: I'm not the downvoter, if someone happens to suspect due to timings.

Comment: @KemyLand I decided against editing, since I already included a note about usability of this pseudo-code in C. However, I can understand that some do not like to see code that needs to be adapted in order to work properly.

Comment: Such pseudo-code is **really** misleading, especially because it does compile as C code and will silently always say "no" (or sometimes "yes" in very unusual circumstances). I have to downvote to move the answer away from views (until it's changed, of course).

Comment: @Ruslan well if you absolutely insist - made it more obvious pseudo code.

Comment: "*`argv` is an array of c-strings*" no, it is not. `argv` is a ***pointer*** to the 1st element of an array of `char*`.