# How can we reference just the string?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define MAXSTR 255 
#define ARGCNT 5 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char cmd[MAXSTR]; 
    char arg1[MAXSTR]; 
    char arg2[MAXSTR]; 
    char file[MAXSTR]; 


    printf("cmd->"); 
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", cmd);
    printf("char %lu=%d\n",strlen(cmd),cmd[strlen(cmd)]); 


    printf("cmd->"); 
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", arg1);
    printf("char %lu=%d\n",strlen(arg1),arg1[strlen(arg1)]); 


    printf("cmd->"); 
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", arg2);
    printf("char %lu=%d\n",strlen(arg2),arg2[strlen(arg2)]); 


    printf("cmd->"); 
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", file);
    printf("char %lu=%d\n",strlen(file),file[strlen(file)]); 


    char ** args = malloc(sizeof(char) * ARGCNT);
    *(args + 0) = cmd; 
    *(args + 1) = arg1; 
    *(args + 2) = arg2; 
    *(args + 3) = file; 
    *(args + 4) = NULL; 


    int *a = *(args + 2);
    printf("TEST =%ls\n",a); 


    for (int i=0;i<ARGCNT;i++) 
        printf("i=%d args[i]=%s\n",i,*(args + i)); 


    int status = execvp(args[0], args); 
    printf("STATUS CODE=%d\n",status);

    return 0; 
}
```

It is the output. TEST =d

```
cmd->a
char 1=0
cmd->s
char 1=0
cmd->d
char 1=0
cmd->f
char 1=0
TEST =d
i=0 args[i]=a
i=1 args[i]=s
i=2 args[i]=d
i=3 args[i]=f
i=4 args[i]=(null)
STATUS CODE=-1
```

How to print the args = arg2? Expect print "arg2" in print("TEST")

OR print "cmd" when a = args + 0

OR print "file" when a = args + 3

The output is the string that I input to args2 now.
Example: input is "ABC", the print will be ABC.

I want to print the string "arg2" instead of what I input.

Comment: Edit your post and fix the code formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can't print variable names in C, those don't exist in the assembly.

Comment: also, the only thing you're going to find at `cmd[strlen(cmd)]` et. al is a NUL terminator, hope it's in bounds.

Comment: `*(args + 0)` is the same as `args[0]` which is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to de-reference each arg, e.g.:

```
printf("%s",*argv[i]);
```

I would also advise re-formatting your question to make it clearer where you are confused.

This is also a duplicate: [printing argv[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860794/how-to-print-argv-arguments-from-main-function-in-c)